# ¿Poner una imagen de preview y título en mi página para que se visualice en Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook

Me gustaría que mi página tenga una imagen de vista previa y un título cuando sea compartida como se ve en este ejemplo ¿que debo agregar a mi página?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en esta página de Mozilla podés encontrar toda la info en la parte "otros tipos de metadatos": https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#otros_tipos_de_metadatos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar etiquetas meta en el `<head>` de tu sitio. Esta es la estructura de la página de esta misma pregunta:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=62634cce9d6c">
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66388/poner-una-imagen-de-preview-y-titulo-en-mi-pagina-para-que-se-visualice-en-face">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver los detalles en [Facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters). Estos siguen el estándar de [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/).

Puedes ver como se ve en el [depurador de contenido compartido](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que añadir una `meta` en tu pagina, con el nombre de `og:image` que haga la referencia a la imagen que quieres que aparezca en esta pagina puede enconrar un ejemplo http://www.tutorialmonsters.com/los-metadatos-de-facebook-etiquetas-meta/

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como se te menciono antes debes colocar las `meta property` para lograr una vista previa de tu sitio web en Facebook. Aunque la respuesta esta como aceptada y te ha servido quiero mencionarte que eso solo te servirá para **Facebook** mas **no** para otras Redes Sociales como **Twitter** que siguen otros estándares de **Open Graph**

Si quieres que te funcione también para Twitter y otras Redes Sociales aquí te dejo un código HTML que debes de colocarlo en tu etiqueta `<head>` como se te menciono anteriormente en la respuesta que aceptaste.

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@TuUsuarioDeTwitter">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@TuUsuarioDeTwitter">
<meta property="og:title" content="El titulo de sitio web">
<meta property="og:description" content="La descripcion de tu sitio web">
<meta property="og:image" content="La url de tu imagen.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://dominio.com">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Colocarlo de esta manera te servirá tanto para **Facebook** como para **Twitter** porque la respuesta de la pregunta de arriba solo te sirve para **Facebook**

**NOTA:** Una vez coloques este código dentro de tu `<heade>` y guardes los cambios. debes de limpiar la chache del navegador ya que es muy posible que no te funcione a la primera

[Mas información en este enlace](https://ed.team/blog/optimiza-tu-web-con-twitter-cards)